# How to troubleshoot with configuring routes in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a web-application in cakephp that

I have 2 routes

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'custom', 'action' => 'home'));
```

(this route works, when i go to localhost i see the correct page)

and

```
Router::connect('/custom/*', array('controller' => 'custom', 'action' => 'actionOnHomePage'));
```

(this route doesn't work) when i go to localhost/custom/actionOnHomePage, i get Page not found error.
Weird because i have a

```
/app/View/Custom/actionOnHomePage - page
```

and I have

```
CustomController::actionOnHomePage
```

in apache error logs i see:

```
[Tue Oct 30 20:53:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/thundr.it/src/app/webroot/custom, referer: http://localhost/
```

So it's referring to the wrong dir because he is looking in webroot. But how to solve it..

Comment: Your url '/custom' will by default go to controller custom which make `Router::connect('/custom/*', array('controller' => 'custom'` is not necessary. Unless you wanted to make every action to go to your actionOnHomePage you can connect it using `Router::connect('/custom/:action/*', array('controller' => 'custom', 'action' => 'actionOnHomePage'));`

Comment: Also make sure that your `/` route is always last in your routes file.

Comment: `/` should not be last as it is not greedy. Routes should be ordered least to most greedy. There is no problem having `/` as the first route as it can only match one single page.

Comment: Thx for the input.
I have removed the second router, but I have the same result in Apache logs.    
I've added on my homepage / default view an echo to see the controller url
    echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'custom','action'=>'actionOnHomePage'),true);
result = http://localhost/custom/actionOnHomePage. So nothing wrong here, I also have my .htaccess files unchanged.

Comment: Okay, I've found the issue, I had to change my documentroot to the parent of app folder and my htaccess file weren't working, because i didn't have the mod_rewrite enabled.